# content is not allowed in prolog .В чем проблема

Tags: xml

Создаю сжатый архив GZIP из своего xml файла и получаю ошибку, при валидации Яндекс.Работа. Как можно решить проблему ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<source creation-time="2019-01-24 16:54:53 GMT+3" host="sait.ru">
 <vacancies>
 <vacancy>
 <url>https://sait.ru/adv303189.html</url>
 <mobile-url></mobile-url>
 <creation-date>2019-01-23 04:25:46 GMT+3</creation-date>
 <update-date>2019-01-24 16:54:53 GMT+3</update-date>
 <salary>0</salary>
 <currency>руб</currency>
 <category>
 <industry>Вакансии, Медицина, фармацевтика, ветеринария</industry>
 </category>
 <job-name>Врач стоматолог-детский</job-name>
 <employment></employment>
 <schedule></schedule>
 <description>Обязанности:  - оказание стоматологической помощи пациентам, в том числе по ДМС - заполнение амбулаторных карт пациентов   Требования:  - Сертификат по специальности - Образование высшее  Условия:  - з/п оклад 25000 руб.+ 20% или от 20% до 30%. - Постоянная, сменный график, работа на территории работодателя - Оформление по ТК РФ - Возможность профессионального обучения за счет работодателя - Ежемесячная финансовая поддержка аренды жилья или ипотеки - Современный стоматологический центр, оказывающий все виды стоматологических услуг.Отличные условия работы.    </description>
 <duty>  - оказание стоматологической помощи пациентам, в том числе по дмс - заполнение амбулаторных карт пациентов   </duty>
 <term><text> работы.    </text></term>
 <requirement>
 <education></education>
 <experience></experience>
 <qualification>  - сертификат по специальности - образование высшее  </qualification>
 </requirement>
 <addresses>

 <address>
                                        <location>Санкт-Петербург</location>
                                        <lng>0</lng>
                                        <lat>0</lat>
                                    </address>
                                </addresses>
 <anonymous-company><description/></anonymous-company>
 </vacancy>
 </vacancies>
 </source>
```

Comment: Ошибка может быть вызвана следующими причинами: 1. Наличие пробельных символов в самом начале документа. 2. Несоответствие кодировок (у вас utf-8, а ожидается, например, utf-16). 3. Ожидается кодировка utf-8 без BOM, а у вас кодировка с BOM (byte order mark). У Яндекса, вроде, часто проблемы именно из-за BOM.

Comment: все перепробовал и ничего не помогает. Подскажите  яндекс пишет в описании:

"YRL-документ должен начинаться со стандартного XML-заголовка с нулевого символа первой строки."

Что такое нулевой символ ?

Comment: Перед `<?xml` не должно быть никаких символов (нечитаемых). Скорее всего, у вас utf-8 с [BOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Маркер_последовательности_байтов). Пересохраните документ в кодировке без BOM.

Comment: я уже просто все убрал в файле и оставил только первую строку, режим без BOM и ничего не происходит, ошибка как и была . 
Вот этот архив, который отправляю яндексу 
https://dropmefiles.com/eOtur

Comment: Проверил: файл действительно без BOM. Не знаю, что еще предпринять.